# Help with developing a combinatorial argument

Tags: combinatorics

I have to make a combinatorial argument for this equation:

$ _{n}P_{k} = _{n-1}P_k + k∙ _{n-1}P_{k-1} $

I cant seem to find examples without binomial theorem. I really dont know where to start with an argument for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $_n P_k$? The number of set **p**artitions of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$ into $k$ subsets?

Comment: It is the formula for permutation. in the book it is defined as "An ordered arrangement of k elements selected from a set of n elements", so i think that fits with what you are saying

Comment: Partitions are not the same as permutations. Which one is it?

Comment: ${}_nP_k$ is a common notation for the number of ordered selections of $k$ elements from a set of size $n$, especially on [calculators](https://slideplayer.com/slide/2454957/8/images/12/Combination+Key+Order%3A+Enter+n+first%2C+press+key%2C+enter+r+next%2C+press+%3D+sign+Unit+0%2C+Session+0.4.jpg). @darijgrinberg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a group of n people who have to be put in k distinct rooms (numbered 1 to k). The number of ways to do that would be nPk. 
An equivalent way to think about the same problem would be to consider one of the n people to be the leader.
Then there are 2 cases, 
1. the leader doesn't get put into one of the rooms(I.e the rooms have to be filled using the n-1 remaining people) : (n-1)Pk
2. The leader does end up in one of the rooms(I.e first the leader picks the room of his choice and then the rest are to be distributed) : kC1 * (n-1)P(k-1)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let the elements be the integers $1,2,\ldots, n$, and consider the case where the element $1$ is among the $k$ elements, and the case where it is not.